# Delete width and height attributes from an image

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7

How can I delete the automatic attributes that Drupal 7 puts on images?

Answer (score 13):

With Drupal 7, you just need to implement `hook_preprocess_image()`, as preprocess functions are executed for every theme function, not just the ones using a template file. In your case, the following code should be enough.

```php
function mymodule_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  foreach (array('width', 'height') as $key) {
    unset($variables[$key]);
  }
}
```

Since `$variables['attributes']` also contains the image attributes, the following code is more complete.

```php
function mymodule_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  $attributes = &$variables['attributes'];

  foreach (array('width', 'height') as $key) {
    unset($attributes[$key]);
    unset($variables[$key]);
  }
}
```

Replace *mymodule* with the short name of your module/theme.

Preprocess functions are preferable when you need to alter the variables passed to a theme function/template file. Theme functions should be overridden only when you need to alter the output they return. In this case, you just need to alter the variables, and thus it is not necessary to override the theme function. Using the preprocess hook, your code will be compatible with future Drupal versions.

Comment: Do you mean "theme_image()" ?! Because I don't thinks there's a function called hook_preprocess_image() in drupal

Comment: `hook_preprocess_image()` is the preprocess function used for `theme_image()`, in the same way `hook_preprocess_node()` is the preprocess function of `theme_node()`. You should never edit a Drupal theme function.

Comment: I'm not talking about editing theme_image(), why can't we use it in template.php file "something like: MyTheme_image()". It's easier this way. -Muhammad.

Comment: See the last three sentences of my answer, which was updated.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I"m trying to do the same thing in Backdrop CMS (which is a fork of Drupal 7). I've placed your code in both a template.php and a theme-settings.php file in the themes main directory but neither way works and the image width and height attributes remain.  Do you know how I could get this to work in Backdrop CMS?